# Wat is the difference between a class component & a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I've been working for a few months now with React. The documentation of React always uses in their example functional components. Now I've seen some other programmers/code examples who uses class components.

What is the difference between those two? When to use a class component and when to use a functional component?

And is there a difference to use a class or a functional compoment when working with Redux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [good article](https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/) which takes a deep look at the technical differences from Dan Abramov, one of the most well-known spokespeople for React.

I can't explain it as well as he does, but the practical differences are relatively small.  However, class components are essentially being deprecated in favor of functional components with [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) which allow writing smaller components with less overhead code and let you group internal side effects more logically and reuse data more easily.

So while currently you can accomplish most tasks with classes or functional components, functional components will eventually replace classes.  And yes, they work with Redux through the use of [redux hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks).

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, class components can have `state` and `props` and functional components can only have `props`. So, functional components are `stateless`, and therefore, simpler.

That was before `hooks`. React is moving away from class components and recommending that everyone move to hooks. Hooks allow you to have a state like functionality within a simpler functional component.

I highly recommend the official documentation. It's easy to follow and very thorough. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

I can't speak to the Redux part. I've never found a use for it, but lots of people do.